# Changing rowId on jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid that contains some data, the first column of which is the numerical PK from the database.

When my delete method gets called, it passes in the rowId of the grid (which it should.)  However, my back end doesn't know what data is on what row.  Is there a way I can set the row ID to my PK field?  Or is there a way to force it to pass in the PK value on delete instead of the row id?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I feel stupid now, the solution is to simply put `key: true` in my colmodel.